# Is there ever a time when wanting to break in a for each loop that using Exit For is a bad idea?

Tags: vb.net

In VB when wanting to break from a for each loop are there times when Exit For is bad practice or is that the best way all of the time?

Comment: What you mean bad practice? `Exit For` just a syntax, same as `Continue For`, cannot say it is _best_ or _bad_...

Comment: There is no such as bad practice when you want to end execution. Its typically used when **1. Continuing to iterate is unnecessary or impossible. This might be caused by an erroneous value or a termination request.
2. An exception is caught in a Try...Catch...Finally. You might use Exit For at the end of the Finally block.
3. There an endless loop, which is a loop that could run a large or even infinite number of times.**  *[see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation.